# React Hook Form controller extract variables

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, controller, react-hook-form, use-form

I have some questions about the react-hook-form controller

https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller

At the moment it looks like this:

```
<Controller
      name="password"
      defaultValue=""
      rules={{ validate: value => isPasswordValid(value) || 'Does not match criteria' }}
      control={control}
      render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
        <PasswordTextField
          error={!!errors.password}
          label="Your password"
          variant="standard"
          value={value}
          inputProps={{ role: 'password' }}
          InputProps={{
            onChange,
            onBlur: () => setFocus(!!password),
            onFocus: () => setFocus(true),
          }}
        />
      )}
    />
```

How do I extract variables that I want to use elsewhere?

Goal is to check if the password input field is empty..

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got this!

You have to import:

```
import classNames from 'classnames';
```

and surround your password field with:

```
className={classNames(classes.passwordField, { [classes.passwordFieldActive]: password.length })}
```

It's a pretty individual case here to be honest, but maybe in your case you probably also extract the password, so you can check if there's a password.length -> truthy